# Is there a name for a basis but without the requirement of every vector having a unique representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

I need some info on bases but without the restriction of any vector having a unique representation, so, for example, if we have a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ with a, let's call it, a "semi-basis" $SB=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, that means that they are linearly independent of each other and every vector $v$ can be represented as linear combination of elements of the semibasis, so, for any $v\in V$, if $e_1,\ldots,e_n\in SB$,

$$v=a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n$$

but it may be that

$$v=a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n=b_1e_1+\cdots+b_ne_n$$

where $a_i\neq b_i$ for some $1\leq i\leq n$. Is there a name for a basis like this? If in vector spaces this condition is impossible and it needs a module or something like that, I consider an answer for them as valid. Thanks.

Comment: A spanning set of vectors.

Comment: If elements in the set are linearly independent, *and* every vector can be represented as a linear combination of elements in the set, then one can show that the representation must be unique. The official name for such set is "basis".

Comment: Non-uniqueness of representation in this spanning set implies **linear dependence**. Note that, if $v = a_1e_1 + \ldots + a_n e_n$, then $e_1\left(a_1 - b_1\right) + \ldots + \left(a_n - b_n\right)e_n = 0$, and this means that the vectors $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ are linearly dependent. This is very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has a name. It is a “spanning set”.

Comment: Would it be a linearly independent spanning set?

Comment: A linearly independent spanning set is a basis.

Comment: @Garmekain Demanding that the spanning set is linearly independent is equivalent to demanding that every vector has a unique representation.

Comment: @5xum Is it just in vector spaces? What about modules or semimodules?

Comment: @Garmekain Isn't your question about vector spaces?

Answer (score 1):

If the vectors are linearly independent and they span $V$ the representation for any vector $v$ is unique that is

$$v=a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n=b_1e_1+\cdots+b_ne_n \iff a_i=b_i$$

and it is by definition a **basis**, indeed

$$a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n=b_1e_1+\cdots+b_ne_n $$

$$\iff (a_1-b_1)e_1+\cdots+(a_n-b_n)e_n=0 \iff  a_i=b_i$$

Otherwise, if the span $V$ and are not linearly independent, we have infinitely many representation for any vector $v$ (assuming the field F infinite) and we define it as a **spanning set**.

Comment: "[...] we have infinitely many representation[s]" : assuming the field $F$ is infinite.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes you are right, I'm referring to that case! In general we can say that we do not have an unique representation.

Answer (score 0):

> ... if we have a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ with a, let's call it, a "semi-basis" $SB=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, that means that they are linearly independent of each other and every vector $v$ can be represented as linear combination of elements of the semibasis ...

If elements in the set $SB$ are linearly "independent", *and* every vector in $V$ can be represented as a linear combination of elements in the set, then one can show that the representation must be **unique**. The official name for such set is "basis". If you don't require linear independence, then there are quite a few ways to describe such a set:

For expressing that a vector space $V$ is a span of a set $S$, one commonly uses the following phrases:

- $S$ spans $V$;
- $V$ is spanned by $S$;
- $S$ is a spanning set of $V$;
- $S$ is a generating set of $V$.

See more in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span